# React native compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin error

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, error-handling, runtime-error

I can start the react native project with no library downloaded. But in some libraries (eg: react-native-safe-area-context) I am getting this error. [enter image description her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqpzR.png)e

Can't find the solution for this error anywhere. I would be glad if you help